# Add columns to a dataframe based on the selection of inputs from widget

Tags: r, shiny

In the dataframe below I want when I select more values from the `selectInput()` more columns to be added in the dataframe like `price,price2,price3` etc instead of having all selected values in one column with many rows.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

### user inter phase
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ### App title ----
  
  
  titlePanel(title="SD")
  ,
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      ### Input files ----
      selectInput("Price","Select the price for analysis", c("List price","End consumer price without VAT", "End consumer price with VAT", "Reimbursed price"),multiple = T),     
       width = 2,
      
    ),
    
    ### Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("Export report", 
                 dataTableOutput("tab7"))
        
      )
      
    )
  )
)


#### Server 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$tab7<-renderDataTable({
    Price<-input$Price
    df<-as.data.frame(list('price' = Price))
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `output$tab7` with this:

```
output$tab7<-renderDataTable({
  if(!is.null(input$Price)) {
    setNames(
      data.frame(t(input$Price)),
      paste0("price",seq_along(input$Price))
    )
  } 
})
```

[image: shiny_price_screenshot]